# Cheetah Print Sunglasses Texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, shaders, photorealism

This is probably a simple question, but I would really appreciate some help here. I am trying to replicate the material of the attached image. I'm a little lost so far and have tried several different methods in the last few hours, like using a mix shader with a noise texture, but can't quite get anything near what I'm looking for. If anyone has any ideas on how I could replicate the look of these sunglasses, I'd really appreciate it.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd say *Musgrave texture* is a good fit.
Good lighting also plays a big part.

[image]

1. Transmission set to 1 for clear plastic
2. Musgrave texture with Color Ramp to control it
3. Mix RGB node to adjust the colors

[image]

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @Jbztexco Glad to be of help :). This was fun.